# How to retrieve limit no of fields from mongodb easily if I have 100s of fields in the collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a sample collection below,

### samplecol:

```
{
key1: 'value1',
key2: 'value2',
key3: 'value3',
key4: 'value4',
key5: 'value5',
key6: 'value6',
key7: 'value7',
key8: 'value8',
key9: 'value9',
key10: 'value10',
key11: 'value11',
key12: 'value12',
key13: 'value13',
key14: 'value14',
}
```

I want to retrieve only 'value14', for that I can write a query like

```
db.samplecol.find(
    {},
    {key1: 0, key2: 0, key3: 0, key4: 0, key5: 0, key6: 0, key7: 0, key8: 0, key9: 0, key10:0, key11: 0, key12: 0, key13: 0, key14:1}
);
```

To retrieve only key14 , i have to make every other keys as 0, if it is 10 or 20 I can manage to write what should i do if I have 100s of fields. 
Is there any easiest way to do like 
`db.samplecol.find({}, {key14: only})`  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It simple will be as following:

```
db.samplecol.find({}, {key14: 1})
```

In that case only `key14` will be fetched.

Here is a useful tutorial about Projection on mongodb site: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#return-the-specified-fields-and-the-id-field-only

Comment: Thank you, its really very simple as you given. I imagined as more.